# What does "T extends Junk" mean in a generic class in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to understand this notation of whats going on here [Example also below](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ106). I'm looking to see if anyone can supply additional code to help me make sense of this. How do I extend junk with T? what does that imply?

```
public class Junk<T extends Junk>
{

    public Junk()
    {

    }

    public T returnType()
    {
        return null; //? what would I even return
    }

    //what would I do to make sense of this class
}
```

Comment: You should read this article to understand it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T` is a generic type parameter. You know it is a Junk, or a subclass of it. To return anything useful from your method, you'd need some other methods using the same type. For example:

```
public class Junk<T extends Junk> {
    T var;

    public void setT(T var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    public T returnType(){
        return var;
    }
}
```

It can be used by creating instances where the type parameter is specified:

```
Junk junk = new Junk<Junk>();
junk.setT(new Junk<Junk>());
junk.returnType();
```

This is more useful than simply using "Junk" instead of "T", because subtypes can be used without losing type-safety. If you have a subclass `SubclassJunk`, then you can do:

```
Junk junk = new Junk<SubclassJunk>();
junk.setT(new SubclassJunk<Junk>());
SubclassJunk subclass = junk.returnType();
```

Answer (score 2):

pardon me for making an educated guess, but,

It looks like `T` is an undefined type,

the statement `<T extends junk>` looks like a constraint to ensure that `T` derives from `Junk`

so if you have a class like

```
public class SmallJunk extends Junk
{

}
```

then `T` can be a`SmallJunk`, but not other types.

Comment: You need `public class SmallJunk extends Junk<SmallJunk>` in order to tell `Junk` what `T` should stand for.

Answer (score 1):

`class Junk<T extends Junk>` is the syntax for generic programming in Java. It means that wherever the type `T` is used in the class, it must stand for *some* (as yet unknown) subclass of `Junk`.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
public class junk<T extends junk<T>>
{

    public T returnType()
    {
        return (T)this;
    }
}
```

you would extend it as

```
public class Subclass extends junk<Subclass> {
}
```

and the inherited `returnType` method would then return `Subclass`.  The most prominent example of this pattern in the standard Java libraries is `enum` types, where an enum `Foo` becomes a class that extends `Enum<Foo>`

Comment: I believe you would still have to cast return "this" to T.

Comment: This is wrong. `T` extends `junk<T>` but `junk<T>` does not necessarily extend `T`

Comment: @newacct See [Angelika Langer's excellent generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ106) for an explanation of how this pattern works for `Enum`.

Comment: @IanRoberts: Umm... I know generics. And I am talking about your `(T)this` being wrong.